# Is a promise the Same as a vow

Tags: oaths

Is a promise the same as a vow
What to do if you break a promise
What to do if you break a vow and a example of a promise and a vow what is a oath

Comment: A promise... to an other person or Allah? it may make a difference, so elaborate give examples make clear what you mean.

Comment: Please use the "edit" link below your post and add this information. Comments are only meant for clarification and not to last forever.

Comment: To be able to help one must understand the question first. And to me it was unclear what you are meaning to say.

Comment: I said what is the difference between a promise and a vow is that not clear enough